# Java integer cyclic iteration shorthand

Tags: java, iteration

When coding I find myself 
doing the following very often:

```
corner++; 
if(corner == 4) corner = 0;
```

Is there anyway do this in one line?

In this example corner should be 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0....

Comment: You may find [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) to be helpful in the future.

Comment: if you find yourself doing something very often, you should consider extracting a method rather than making the code shorter (which is often  less readable)

Answer (score 31):

You can use this short and kind of readable line ([Demo](https://ideone.com/H3GzbE)):

```
corner = (corner + 1) % 4;
```

Or, even a tiny bit shorter ([Demo](https://ideone.com/xBNeN3)):

```
corner = ++corner % 4;
```

Answer (score 8):

Use remainder. It's two lines but clean.

```
corner++;
corner %= 4;
```

Comment: What's more efficient mod or if? To be honest I'm just curios at this point.

Comment: @TheJohnMajor01: sorry but that's pure premature optimization. They both are trivially brief.

Comment: Much more important is what is easier to understand and debug 5 months later.

Comment: @TheJohnMajor01 `if` is faster. Mod & division are really slow.

Comment: @Boann First of all, it won't matter at all. But a mod with a constant can be converted to an `and` op (if you can't prove that corner is always positive the compiler will need a handful more) which is *probably* going to be faster than the branch. And the most important thing: You really can't make any such blanket statements since there are many, many different CPU architectures around with some very different characteristics (a branch is prohibitively expensive on SIMD architectures, which happen to be really good at doing divisions)

Comment: @Tunaki I posted your comment as answer.

Comment: @Voo It's worse than that, this is specifically targeting Java, which may do a whole mess of runtime optimizations, including unrolling the loop so that the %4 disappears completely.

Comment: @Morgen Not that gcc/clang/etc. wouldn't also perform that sort of optimization if requested, albeit at compile-time.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
corner = ++corner == 4 ? 0 : corner;
```

This would give you the possibility to assign something else to the `corner` variable in case your `corner == 4` test didn't pass.

Comment: While true, one must mention to argue against striving for such brevity as it will likely make it harder to understand the code at a glance, making it harder for future coders who must maintain the code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels While you are also right, the OP is looking for brevity, not clarity; & he shall get what he asked for.

Comment: The is neither brief *nor* clear. It's just a mess. -1

Comment: @jpmc26 the concept of brevity differs from on person's view to another; it' s debatable. But when it comes to the OP's question, he asked for a **one-liner** , & that's what this answer **officially targets**.

Comment: This is also hardly complicated code, the ternary statement is a very simple structure. Granted, `(corner + 1)` would be more clear than `++corner`, but this is not complicated stuff.

Comment: @MohammedAoufZOUAG: `if (++corner == 4) corner = 0;` would be one line as well, and much clearer - and even shorter.

Comment: @Bergi you are right. But in addition to what Morgen said, I think that if you know how does the ternary operator work, then this far enough from complicated.

Comment: Some of my rules of thumb are to 1. avoid code where the outcome is different depending on the difference between `++x` and `x++`, and 2. avoid code where a value is read, modified and written in the same statement in a non-trivial way (as `corner` in this example). But everybody may have his subjective priorities here....

Answer (score 3):

I use:

```
if (++corner == 4) corner = 0;
```

Comment: I downvoted this because using `++` inline is too confusing. It's hard to keep the order of operations straight in my head when I read it, and it's easy to miss that the `if` statement contains side effects.

Comment: @jpmc26 I could understand if it was `corner++`. But it's `++corner` so the order of operations is a completely straightforward left-to-right.

Answer (score 1):

It is not so *obvious* but much **faster**, since division generally executes slower than any bitwise operation.

```
corner = ++corner & 3;
```

EDIT: And surprisingly I discovered one more awesome way to make cycling - using shifts, and it runs **even faster!**

```
corner = ++corner << 30 >>> 30;
```

And this trick only works for any power of 2.

[This benchmark](http://jsperf.com/cyclic-iteration) shows all the results (though it's javascript, not java)